# Flex Method on Leave TextInput

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone know of an event that can be called after a user clicks out of a TextInput?

I would like the user to enter information, and when they finish I would like to format the information.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

That's `valueCommit` event you're looking for. It fires when user changed text and set focus to something else.

Comment: valueCommit results in a event recursion loop when trying to format the TextInput that fires the event.

Comment: Then consider using one part of `valueCommit` - `focusOut` event (maybe in combination with `change`).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the onBlur event which occurs on an element when it loses focus, i.e when a user clicks outside that specific element

Comment: onBlur is not a Flex Mobile event that I can tell. focusOut, however, is and functions like you described, thank you!